# Error at login page after changing application environment in codeigniter

Tags: xampp, codeigniter-3, production-environment

Sorry to all, I have a problem at login page in codeigniter after changing application environment from development to production.

Previously it was working fine but now the login page fail at all. Here is the screenshot.

[click here to see a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIu9.png)

The followings are the versions of PHP, APACHE and CI version.
Windows Version:  Pro  64-bit, 
XAMPP Version: 7.1.7, 
Control Panel Version: 3.2.2,
CI version 3.1.7

Please anybody with help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was 'echo ENVIRONMENT'; in index.php and 'echo ['base_url'] in conf.php, I deleted these lines and worked fine.

NOTE: these lines 'echo ENVIRONMENT'; and and 'echo ['base_url']; was added by myself in index.php and conf.php respectively